# Tic-Tac-Toe Game c++

Tags: c++

**XO Game C++**

This code returns only "It’s a Tie !!" .. What's the error in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3;

scanf("%c%c%c\n%c%c%c\n%c%c%c",&a1,&b1,&c1,&a2,&b2,&c2,&a3,&b3,&c3);

if(a1==b1==c1=='X'||a2==b2==c2=='X'||a3==b3==c3=='X'||a1==a2==a3=='X'
   ||b1==b2==b3=='X'||c1==c2==c3=='X'||a1==b2==c3=='X'||c1==b2==a3=='X'){

    printf("X wins\n");

   }

if(a1==b1==c1=='O'||a2==b2==c2=='O'||a3==b3==c3=='O'||a1==a2==a3=='O'
   ||b1==b2==b3=='O'||c1==c2==c3=='O'||a1==b2==c3=='O'||c1==b2==a3=='O'){

    printf("O wins\n");

   }

if(a1!=b1!=c1||a2!=b2!=c2||a3!=b3!=c3||a1!=a2!=a3
   ||b1!=b2!=b3||c1!=c2!=c3||a1!=b2!=c3||c1!=b2!=a3){

    printf("It’s a Tie !!\n");

   }
}
```

Comment: It's simple: `a1==b1==c1=='X'` doesn't even remotely do what you're expecting.

Comment: Surely its a tie when all the last if tests are true, not just one

Comment: See the right hand side under the _related_ questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a1==b1==c1=='X'
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. It compares `a1` to the boolean result of `b1==c1=='X'`, probably giving `false`.

To check whether they are all equal, you need

```
a1=='X' && b1=='X' && c1=='X'
```